# How to access object created in one for loop within another for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have a function that contains a for-loop. In this for-loop I save 4 different strings to object `saveImageTitles`. At the run-through of the last item in the for loop I trigger another function `appendObject()` that contains yet another for-loop.

In the for loop function in `appendObject();` I want to pass on each string from `saveImageTitles` via `someOtherFunction(objectIndex].image[j], saveImageTitles[j]);` - but  `saveImageTitles[j]` will turn up as *undefined*.

How do I save my strings from the one for loop so that I can iterate through them in my second for-loop?

EDIT: Added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MEhzw/4/)

```
var saveImageTitles = [];
var objectIndex = 0;
var objectCount = 4;
var totalObjectImages = 1;

function appendObject() {
  for(var j in products[objectIndex].image) {

 /* function where i want to pass on each string */     
    someOtherFunction(products[objectIndex].image[j], saveImageTitles[j]);

 /* ISSUE - WILL ONLY PRINT OUT THE FIRST ITEM */
    console.log(saveImageTitles[j]); 
  } 
}

function saveObject() {
    for(var r in products[objectIndex].image_titles)
    {
        saveImageTitles = products[objectIndex].image_titles[r];

        if(totalObjectImages == objectCount) { //equals to the last item in the for loop
            appendObject();
        }
        totalObjectImages++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value for j there? Are you sure that index exists in the numerically indexed `saveImageTitles` array?

Comment: I think you want to use `saveImageTitles.push(products[objectIndex].image_titles[r]);` instead of `saveImageTitles = products[objectIndex].image_titles[r];`

Comment: Patrick Q - That did it! Post an answer and ill accept it.